# Is it possible to accelerate the update of users's tab on GIS Meta

Tags: support, status-bydesign, votes, users

Let's take as an example the tab [voters filtered per week](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=week). There are zero voters this week and surely this is not true.

This way it looks nobody is participating and might cause a bad impression.

What is the purpose to have a voters tab per week opened for all community if it is not possible to retrieve updated information from it?

Comment: This question belongs on the SE meta because it's a system-wide issue.

Comment: It will get *way* more attention on the SE meta (if it's not a duplicate) because there are far more users there.  Note that MSO is a *system* wide meta page and welcomes questions about how SE works in general.

Comment: @whuber Please don't migrate questions like this to MSO just to "get more attention". We monitor all child metas, and this seems like a fairly GIS-specific issue at the moment.

Comment: @Anna The migration was not to get more attention--it was specifically because the question addresses system wide behavior, not GIS-only behavior.  Shog9's answer confirms this expectation.

Comment: @whuber Since the confusion arose here, it's even better for you to keep the question here - to make sure other folks on this site aren't similarly confused in the future. The network-wide meta is certainly handy, but most people here shouldn't have to worry about two separate sites.

Comment: @Anna When a question arises on a site like meta GIS, it is reasonable to suppose that thoughtful or observant members in many other communities will raise the same issue sooner or later. The motivation for migration, then, is to stave off 100 different sites eventually having to address the same question: isn't that one of the reasons for MSO to exist? I wouldn't be unhappy if you said that's wrong (only a little puzzled) and would be pleased to modify my migration policy accordingly.

Comment: @whuber It's a weird chicken-and-egg thing with no clear answer, unfortunately. Sure, the same problem might arise on other sites, but those other sites also might not know (nor should they, necessarily) about the network meta, so the same questions are going to get asked anyway. With 100+ sites, it ends up being more expedient for each community to just take care of itself instead of trying to decide what's network-worthy and what isn't.

Comment: @Anna Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not about update frequency. It's about vote-totals:

[image: vote tab tooltip]

While 28 people have voted here this month, no one's voted more than 10 times. The votingest voter has cast only 8 votes. So, no one meets the 10-vote threshold for display on the page.